# SAS Hash Merge Macro - output multiple data sets

Tags: hash, merge, sas

I'm working on creating a hash merge macro and I want to create a data set for the merged table and data sets for missing values. Here is an example of what I'm looking for with a regular merge.

```
data &onto miss&varnm xtra&varnm;
  merge &onto(in=in1) fr2(in=in2);
    by &byvars;
    if in2 then from = "&from";
    else from = "&onto";
    if in1 and in2 then output &onto;
    else if in1 and not in2 then output &onto miss&varnm;
    else if not in1 and in2 then output xtra&varnm;
run;
```

I think I've got the merge running pretty well but I'm not sure how to go about getting the 'missing' data sets so any help would be appreciated.

```
%macro hashmerge(varnm,onto,from,byvars);
/* The inputs are the variables to merge,
   the merge onto data set, the merge from
   data set and the key(s). vanrnm and 
   byvars are set up to accept multiple inputs. */

%let data_vars   = %trim   (&varnm);
%let data_vars_a = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_vars.,%str( ),%str(",")));
%let data_vars_b = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_vars.,%str( ), %str(,)));
%let data_key    = %trim   (&byvars);
%let data_key    = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_key.,%str( ), %str(",")));

data &onto(drop=rc);
set &onto &from(keep=&varnm &byvars);

 declare hash h_merge (dataset: "&from.");

 rc = h_merge.DefineKey  ("&data_key.");
 rc = h_merge.DefineData ("&data_vars_a.");
 rc = h_merge.DefineDone ();

 do until (eof);
   set &onto end = eof;
   call missing(&data_vars_b.);
   rc = h_merge.find ();
   output;
 end;
stop;
run;

%mend;
```

Comment: Are you only using this for one-to-one merges?

Comment: No, I'll be using this for different merges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way you've set up your hash object you can't easily get the `xtra` dataset. You'll be able to get the `miss` and `onto` ones without too much bother via something like this, plus the necessary change to your `data` statement:

```
if rc = 0 then output &onto;
else output miss&varnm;
```

However, to find all the values in your `from` dataset that you haven't used yet that would normally go to the `xtra` dataset, you'll need to keep track of which values you *have* used as you do the merge, then at the end of the data step copy the rest into a new hash object and output that object.

N.B. with your current code all rows are output to the `&onto` dataset even if they have missing values for your lookup variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is little hard to do this but here you have sample idea how it could be done.

Create another hash hash object, just like first one. From second object you will remove items allready matched. At the end you just output second object to data set. It takes doble the memory for hash objects but its first attempt.

(Didn't run code and sorry for any errors)

```
%macro hashmerge(varnm,onto,from,byvars);
/* The inputs are the variables to merge,
   the merge onto data set, the merge from
   data set and the key(s). vanrnm and 
   byvars are set up to accept multiple inputs. */

%let data_vars   = %trim   (&varnm);
%let data_vars_a = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_vars.,%str( ),%str(",")));
%let data_vars_b = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_vars.,%str( ), %str(,)));
%let data_key    = %trim   (&byvars);
%let data_key    = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_key.,%str( ), %str(",")));

data &onto (drop=rc);
   if 0 set &onto &from(keep=&varnm. &byvars.);   

   declare hash h_merge    (dataset: "&from.");
   rc = h_merge.DefineKey  ("&data_key.");
   rc = h_merge.DefineData ("&data_vars_a.");
   rc = h_merge.DefineDone ();

   /*hash table that will hold data not yet founded by find method */
   declare hash h_merge_copy    (dataset: "&from.");
   rc = h_merge_copy.DefineKey  ("&data_key.");
   rc = h_merge_copy.DefineData ("&data_vars_a.");
   rc = h_merge_copy.DefineDone ();

   do until (eof);

      set &onto. end = eof;

      if h_merge.find () = 0 then do;
         /*removing data from h_merge_copy if founded and if not allready removed*/
         if h_merge_copy.check() = 0 then do;
            rc = h_merge_copy.remove();
         end;
      end;
      else
         output miss&varnm.; /*no find match - output to miss&varnm.*/

      output &onto.; /*find match in hash or not output to &onto. (left join)*/
   end;

   h_merge_copy.output(dataset: "&onto.");

   stop;
run;

%mend;
```

I can improve this to consume little less memory like no storing data in second hash but today it is allready too late. Hope this helped a little.

Comment: If it's a one to one merge, couldn't this approach work with just one hash table?  If Find() succeeds you can remove() since you only need to read each record once.

Comment: @Quentin You are right but I made more generalized approach. If one2one then it can be one hash.

Comment: So with this approach you could have duplicate by values in &onto, but it could not handle duplicate by values in &from, correct?

Comment: Hash object by default doesn't allow to have duplicates by key records. You must explicitly define hash as multidata to be able to load multiple records with the sama key.

Comment: So Worth noting for OP that this approach expects the &from dataset to be unique by the &byvars.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help and suggestions. I wasn't sure how to add the 'xtra' data set without creating another hash which defeats the purpose of the hash merge. So here's what I have to create the missing and merged data set.

```
%macro hashmerge(varnm,onto,from,byvars);


%let data_vars   = %trim   (&varnm);
%let data_vars_a = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_vars.,%str( ),%str(",")));
%let data_vars_b = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_vars.,%str( ), %str(,)));
%let data_key    = %trim   (&byvars);
%let data_key    = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_key.,%str( ), %str(",")));

data &onto(drop=rc) miss&varnm(drop=rc);
   if 0 then set &onto &from(keep=&varnm. &byvars.);

   declare hash h_merge (dataset: "&from.");
   rc = h_merge.DefineKey  ("&data_key.");
   rc = h_merge.DefineData ("&data_vars_a.");
   rc = h_merge.DefineDone ();

   do until (eof);
     set &onto end = eof;
     call missing(&data_vars_b.);
     rc = h_merge.find ();
     if rc = 0 then do;
       output &onto;
       from = "&from.";
     end;
     else do;
       output miss&varnm &onto;
       from = "&onto.";
     end;
   end;

stop;
run;

%mend;
```

If you wanted to only include the non-missing values to the new data set or remove the 'from' variable it would be simple enough to modify the code.

Please post a suggestion if anyone knows a more efficient way to do this.